# how to bind gridview present in user control from aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in aspx page. I have a gridview in user control.I have placed the user control in aspx page.How to bind the gridview on selectIndexChanged event of the dropdownlist. I want to pass the dropdownlist selected index to a function and then bind gridview which is in user control.I want to bind the gridview from aspx.cs.

ASPX page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/HomePage.master" Inherits="Main" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="UserControl" Src="~/UserControl.ascx" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="WebControls" Namespace="WebControls" TagPrefix="cc" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" ID="mainPart" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, EmpName %>">></asp:Label>
    <cc:CstDropDown ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </cc:CstDropDown>
    <uc:UserControl ID="UsrCtrl" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="subContent" ID="sub" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

ASCX page

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl" %>

   <asp:GridView ID="dataGrid"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="EmpID" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowEditing="dataGrid_RowEditing"
     OnRowCancelingEdit="dataGrid_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="dataGrid_RowUpdating">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the binding method in user control UsrCtrl public and call it from selectedIndexChange event of dropdown in the main page.

**In UsrCtrl**

```
public void BindMyGrid(string selectedValue)
{
     //Bind grid here
}
```

**In aspx Main.aspx**

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
{
   UsrCtrl.BindMyGrid(ddl.SelectedValue);

}
```

Comment: Thanks.But how can i bind the gridview on OnRowEditing event because here i have to get the dropdown list selected value. OnRowEditing event will be written in UsrCtrl.cs file.

Comment: OnRowEditing event is in UserControl.

Comment: Now you want SelectedValue of dropdownlist in Main page in the OnRowEditing event in the UsrCtrl ?

Comment: Exactly right. how can i have that SelectedValue of dropdownlist in  usercontrol?

Comment: Make a public method in Main which returns the selected value of dropdownlist and call from UsrCtrl,  OnRowEditing